# Magento Current Path

Tags: magento-1.9, menu, paths

I want to show current menu path to users in Magento. it will good if I can show it under top menu. How i can show user the navigated path to current page?

Comment: did you mean `breadcrumbs` ?

Comment: Yes, I mean to show breadcrumbs.

Comment: By default breadcrumbs is active, but when user find product with instant search and navigate to product page , the breadcrumbs is not shown. How i can active it when navigate by instant search result ?

Answer (score 0):

You need to tell Magento which menu you want highlighted in the controller action by calling the _setActiveMenu method.

```
$this->_setActiveMenu('tutorial_menu/first_page');
```

Your config.xml file will look like:

```
<config>

<!-- ... -->
<adminhtml>
    <menu>
        <tutorial_menu translate="title" module="adminhelloworld">
            <title>Tutorial Menu</title> 
            <sort_order>9999</sort_order>
            <children>
                <first_page module="adminhelloworld">
                    <title>Our First Page</title> 
                    <action>adminhelloworld/index/index</action>
                </first_page>
            </children>
        </tutorial_menu>
    </menu>    
</adminhtml>
<!-- ... -->
```